# Powershell Export-CSV with the path as a variable

Tags: powershell

I have a script that displays the Active Directory computers in a CSV list. If I define the path for Export-CSV as plain text, everything works fine. However, when I try to recreate the path with variables using Join-Path, I get the error that the argument cannot be bound to the "Path" parameter because it is NULL.

Does anyone know how i could solve the problem?

Script:

```
$Export_Path_External = "\\${env:COMPUTERNAME}." + "${env:USERDNSDOMAIN}" + "\C$\users\bob"

$AD_Server_Name = 'ADServer.local'

$Administrator = 'Domain\Administrator'

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $AD_Server_Name -Credential $Administrator -ScriptBlock {
$AD_Clients = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "PC-*"' | select-object -Property Name | Export-Csv (Join-Path $Export_Path_External -ChildPath "Active_Directory_Clients.csv") -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: You want the remote session to write a CSV back to the admin share on your own computer? Why not pipe the output from `Invoke-Command` to `Export-Csv` instead?

Comment: If you want the server to write the file onto its own C drive, then use a LOCAL path for this server: `"C:\users\bob"`. If you want the output written to **your** local machine then do what @MathiasR.Jessen commented. Either way, you'll want a local path

Comment: ^ my thoughts exactly. Your immediate fix would be to use it as a remote variable `$using:Export_Path_External`, but the more logical approach would be to pipe it after your `Invoke-Command`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that the variable $Export_Path_External does not exist in the remote session only your local session. To use it you need to reference it as `$using:Export_Path_External`
However you will then likely run in to a kerberos double hop issue when making a connection back to your computer. See the suggestions others have made in the comments.